# Is there a name for a topological embedding (of a semiring) into itself?

Tags: general-topology, terminology, semiring

The injective continuous map $h:X\to Y$ is a topological embedding if it is a homeomorphism onto the image of $h$ in $Y$.

Let the function $h:X\to Y$ be a topological embedding and let $X=Y$ be a semiring.

Does this have a special name or notable properties in respect of either a) being a topological embedding **in itself** and b) being a topological emmbedding **in a semiring**?

**Motivation**

I don't believe this adds anything to the question tbh. but I was advised to add it.  I'm making slow progress proving the following:

> Let $T$ be the unique homeomorphism on the 2-adic numbers which topologically conjugates $f(x)=3x+2^{\nu_2(x)}$ to $g(x)=x-2^{\nu_2(x)}$

> Let $X$ be the semiring of positive ternary rationals as a subspace of $\Bbb Z_2$ .
> I want to show that $T$ is a topological embedding of $X$ in itself.

but I'm just working from scratch algebraically treating $X$ as a set (susbset of $\Bbb R$), not using the concepts of topological embedding, nor the semiring other than closure under addition and multiplication, and I wanted to see if there's any material on how this concept (of a topological embedding on a semiring) can be of help, if at all.

Comment: This question is vague, it includes multiple questions in itself. Moreover questions of the type "does the property A have a name" are usually in the negative, and if its in the negative then no one can answer it.

Comment: @Jakobian thank-you for the feedback. I dispute your claim that the question is vague in fact I still believe it to be an entirely precise question notwithstanding your comment.  In respect of your comment re "does x have a name" usually being negative, do I understand correctly that your claim, if true, would render the *terminology* tag defunct? I have asked such questions in the past and an answer has returned with the correct terminology for the object in question.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking on what I said and I agree the question is not vague. However there are other issues. It's still multiple questions in one, moreover, there is no real motivation here, in other words, your question seems to come out of nowhere. Could you draw some kind of context to make this question relevant to this site?

Comment: @Jakobian the motivation is that I need to study the case in question and I seek the most relevant material so i can get some insights . I don't think giving the very precise case would add anything to the question. This is my case: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148510/temp

Comment: I still think it's a good idea to add it to your question. Even if it doesn't benefit the question overall, it won't be posed as isolated anymore.

Comment: @Jakobian ok done, thank-you for your help.